# Как сделать, чтобы цикл while продолжал работать дальше?

Tags: python

Написал код, который находит самое наибольшее число в списке и вычисляет, сколько раз к другим числам надо добавить единицу, чтобы они сравнялись. В конце выводит количество этих добавленных единиц. Но вот проблема, если в списке есть два/три/четыре и т.д "больших числа", например [1,2,3,1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3]. То мой код доходит до первой тройки от начала и первой от конца, а то, что в середине - не видит. Понимаю, что мог изначально выбрать неверный путь решения, но очень хотелось бы получить подсказку именно **в таком ключе**. Заранее спасибо всем отозвавшимся)

```
def candies(a):
    c = len(a)
    d = []
    e = 0
    f = -1

    if c<= 1:
        print(-1)
    else:
        b = max(a)
        while a[e] < b:
            a[e]+=1
            d.append(1)
            if a[e] == b:
                e+=1
        while a[f] < b:
            a[f]+=1
            d.append(1)
            if a[f] == b:
                f-=1
        print(len(d))
candies([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Это довольно странная попытка решения. Зачем вы идёте по элементам до максимального если можно просто пройтись по массиву добавляя в счётчик значение `b - a[e]`?

Comment: Ну потому что ты осознал, что можно сделать так, а я нет)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, что надо сделать, то я сделал так.

```
def candies(a):
    e = 0
    b = max(a)
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if len(a) <= 1:
            print(-1)
        else:
            if a[i] < b:
                while a[i] != b:
                    e += 1
                    a[i] += 1
    print(e)

candies([4, 3, 6, 7, 2, 1])
```

Я старался не сильно менять ваше решение. Счетчик единиц можно ввести как переменную, которая будет изменяться на 1 одновременно с добавлением единицы. Введение отдельного массива визуально нагружает код, ну и сложнее его воспринимать.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!! Слишком сложно осознать, что четыре условия идут подряд - for, else, if, while)))

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой пример:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]

candies = lambda x: sum([max(x) - num for num in x])

print(candies(my_list))
```

---

```
6
```

Можно переписать как обычную функцию и определить внутри её максимальный элемент, присвоить его переменной и выиграть еще немного в производительности.

Comment: Для меня пока очень тяжело осознавать, что есть такое эта лямбда и что вообще с ней делать(

Comment: Всё впереди) это как обычная функция, только для простоты она описана в одну строку. Всё, что идёт после lambda и до символа ":" - это передаваемые аргументы (в нашем случае мы передаем список). А ко всему, что идет после ":" - можно написать return ... чего-то там.